# Meaning of axis of figures of simulation or performance modeling papers

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, data-modeling, simulation, hpc

I am reading some papers on simulation and performance modeling. The Y axis in some figures is labeled "Seconds per Simulation Day". I am not sure what it actually means. It span from 0, 20, 40 to 120.

Another label is "Simulation years per day". I guess it means the guest OS inside simulation environment thinks it has passed several years while actually it just passed a day in the real world? But I guess simulation should slow down the execution, so I guess inside simulation environment passed several hours while actually it just passed a day in the real world would be more reasonable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the paper, I assume they are trying to compare the CPU time it takes to get to some physical time in a simulation.

So "Seconds per Simulation Day" is likely the walltime it took to get 24 hours in the simulation.

Likewise, "Simulation Years per Day" is physical time of simulation/real life day.

Of course, without seeing the paper it's impossible to know for sure. It's also possible they are looking at CPU-seconds or CPU-days, which would be nCPUs*walltime.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. But in a cycle by cycle simulation. Is it possible to make the simulation environment simulate a day within several seconds? I am kinda confused because the simulator needs several instructions to simulate one instruction. So the simulation should go slower, in my understanding.

Comment: Again, without the paper, there's no indication what the simulation is you're talking about. I work in fluid dynamics and we use the same kinds of metrics -- CPU time per simulation second, etc.. Can you post links to the paper in your question so the answer can be clarified?

Comment: Right, so just as I said in the answer -- Figure 28 for example is looking at how many years can be simulated by the CAM atmospheric code per real-world day as a function of number of processes. In this case threads and MPI processes. So they are trying to show scaling of the code as number of processors increases. A linear slope would be perfect scaling.

Comment: @Sean If you still aren't clear on what these graphs mean, edit your question to include what you want to know and I'll answer it. We can iterate until you get it all answered.

Answer (score 0):

Simulations typically run in discrete time units, called *time steps*. If you'd like to simulate a certain process that spans certain time in the simulation, you would have to perform certain number of time steps. If the length of a time step is fixed, the number of steps is then just the simulated time divided by the length of the time step. Calculations in each time step take certain amount of time and the total run time for the simulation would equal the number of time steps times the time it takes to perform one time step:

```
(1) total_time = (simulation_time / timestep_length) * run_time_per_timestep
```

Now several benchmark parameters can be obtained by placing different parameters on the left hand side. E.g. if you fix `simulation_time = 1 day` then `total_time` would give you the total simulation run time, i.e.

```
(2) seconds_per_sim_day = (1 day / timestep_length) * run_time_per_timestep
```

Large values of `seconds_per_sim_day` could mean:

- it takes too much time to compute a single time step, i.e. `run_time_per_timestep` is too high -> the computation algorithm should be optimised for speed;
- the time step is too short -> search for better algorithms that can accept larger time steps and still produce (almost) the same result.

On the other hand, if you solve `(1)` for `simulation_time` and fix `total_time = 1 day`, you get the number of time steps that can be performed per day times the length of the time step, or the total simulation time that can be achieved per day of computation:

```
(3) simulation_time_per_day = (1 day / run_time_per_step) * timestep_length
```

Now one can observe that:

- larger time steps lead to larger values of `simulation_time_per_day`, i.e. longer simulations can be computed;
- if it takes too much time to compute a time step, the value of `simulation_time_per_day` would go down.

Usually those figures could be used when making decisions about buying CPU time at some computing centre. For example, you would like to simulate 100 years, then just divide that by the amount of simulation years per day and you get how many compute days you would have to pay (or wait) for. Larger values of `simulation_time_per_day` definitely benefit you in this case. If, on the other hand, you only have 10 compute days at your disposal, then you can compute how long of a simulation could be computed and make some decisions, e.g. more short simulations but with many different parameters vs. less but longer simulations with some parameters that you have predicted to be the optimal ones.

In real life things are much more complicated. Usually computing each time step could take different time (although there are cases where each time step takes exactly the same amount of time as all other time steps) and it would strongly depend on the simluation size, configuration, etc. That's why standardised tests exist and usually some averaged value is reported.

Just to summarise: given that all test parameters are kept equal,

- faster computers would give less "seconds per simulation day" and more "simulation years per day"
- slower computers would give more "seconds per simulation day" and less "simulation years per day"

By the way, both quantites are reciprocial and related by this simple equation:

```
simuation_years_per_day = 236,55 / seconds_per_simulation_day
```

(that is "simulation years per day" equals 86400 divided by "seconds per simulation day" /which gives you the simulation days per day/ and then dividied by 365.25 to convert the result into years)

So it doesn't really matter if "simulation years per day" or "seconds per simulation day" is presented. One just have to chose the representation which clearly shows how much better the newer system is from the previous/older/existing one :)